# How can I loop through a checkbox array and insert into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Update:
The checkbox array works and fills with the appropriate data. Now I need to insert the data from the checkbox array into MySQL. Something is going awry with this code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check1'])) {
foreach($_POST['check1'] as $check) { 
    $exclude_arr[] = $check;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($exclude_arr); $j++){
        $exclude = $exclude_arr[$j];
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO exclude (name) VALUES ('.$exclude.')';
        $dbhc->query($sql);
    }
  }
}
```

Previous: I have an HTML table with an array of checkboxes in the last column. I would like to take all of the selected checkboxes and insert their value into a MySQL table. The values of the checkboxes are names being pulled from a different MySQL table. I'm having issues looping through the array of checkboxes.

```
<?php
$dbhc = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database') or die(mysql_error());
echo "<form action=\"file.php\" method=\"post\">
<table border='0'>
    <tr>
        <th>strategygame</th>
        <th width='130px'>approachpath</th>
        <th width='130px'>universe</th>
        <th width='130px'>strategylevel</th>
        <th width='130px'>capacity</th>
        <th width='130px'>exclude</th>
    </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $localcounter = $localcounter + 1;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['strategygame'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['approachpath'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['universe'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format($row['strategylevel'], 0, '.', ',') . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format($row['capacity'], 0, '.', ',') . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check1[{$row['id']}]\" value=\"{$row['strategygame']}\"/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save Selection\"/> 
</form>";
if(!empty($_POST['check1'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check1'] as $check) { 
        $exclude_arr[] = $check;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($exclude_arr); $j++){
            $exclude = $exclude_arr[$j];
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO exclude (name) VALUES ('.$exclude.')';
            $dbhc->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: In your PHP error log are you getting error, foreach has an invalid argument?

Comment: @AliExalter: I am getting this error in my PHP error log: `[20-Nov-2013 09:01:20] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/user/public_html/website/folder/file.php on line 21`

Comment: And this is not this file. As in your code above, your form action is file.php and the loop is not in file.php, it is on the page which has the form. Also I just notice your `INSERT` QUERY has `$name`, where is that coming from.

Comment: @AliExalter: $name has been changed to $exclude. How can I coordinate the form and the loop?

Comment: If the loop and form is on same page then Your form should submit (form action) on the same page where the loop is. First time when the page load it is not getting the POST data. It only gets when the form submit. Your form is sending POST data to file.php. Is this code from file.php?

Comment: It seems like your form is submitting data to somewhere else (file.php) not where the loop is. Thats why you are getting nothing in POST on this file.

Comment: @AliExalter, okay. All of the code shown above is located within file.php. I have added a submit button to the form.

Comment: Now it is filling the post variables. I am getting results in the error log from error_log(print_r($_POST,true));

Comment: Is it inserting in SQL exclude table? It must be inserting something. First check $_POST['check1'] should not be empty in error log.

Comment: It is not inserting into the SQL Exclude table. `$_POST['check1']` does return the values from the selected checkboxes.

Comment: check whats in `error_log(print_r($exclude_arr[],true))` before for ($j=0... line. If it will be 1 value then no need to loop again.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try that: `Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /home/user/public_html/website/folder/file.php on line 92`

Comment: type this `error_log(print_r($exclude_arr,true))` no [] brackets. they were just to tell you that print_r is used to print arrays in string format.

Comment: `error_log(print_r($exclude_arr,true))` returns null.

Comment: can you print your error_log() for $_POST here so i can see whats in check1 (array or object) and do you need to loop twice.

Comment: $_POST error_log(): `[20-Nov-2013 13:27:31] Array
(
    [check1] => Array
        (
            [BOB] => BOB
            [BILLY] => BILLY
        )

)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking just at the html, a problem you will run into, is that only checked checkboxes are sent to the server, so you never actually know which box represents which row in your database, for two sent in forms, for example `$_POST['check1'][3]` will represent different things.

The first thing I would change, is to make sure your checkboxes are easily identifyable, using for example something like:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check1[{$row['id']}]\" value=\"{$row['strategygame']}\"/>
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ don't use echo here, you are already echoing
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ add an identifier to the checkbox
```

As you can see above, I have also removed the `echo` statement as you are already echoing.

Also, I don't know where `$name` comes from in your sql statement, but you probably have an sql injection problem.

Comment: You should add the fact that nowhere is the OP defining the value of the `$name` variable that is being inserted into the database.

Comment: @fletch Funny, I just did that :)

Comment: Nice job. :)
 I didn't want to post a new answer just to mention that. I suppose I could have added that the OP also has what appears to be a redundant loop which would allow for duplicate rows in the `exclude` table.

Comment: @fletch To be honest, the double loop with the sql does not make any sense to me, but that will be the next problem, right now there is not even a sensible form to process...

Comment: Switched the $name variable to $exclude and updated above code. The goal is for the name column in the MySQL Insert to equal the value of 'strategygame' for all of the checkboxes. Currently not getting any errors, but not inserting into MySQL either.

Comment: use `error_log(print_r($_POST,true));` to see if you are getting something in POST or not. As you are using MAMP or LAMP empty your PHP error log and then submit the form again.

Comment: @AliExalter: Results from the error log: Looks like nothing is being posted. [20-Nov-2013 09:52:41] Array
    (
)

[20-Nov-2013 09:52:45] Array
(
)

[20-Nov-2013 09:52:55] Array
(
)